# Correct architecture for prototype objects

Tags: javascript, architecture, prototypejs

Seeing as you can't access properties of sibling methods in a javascript object, I've been using the prototype method to extend those properties.

```
var ColorGen = function ColorGen() {}

ColorGen.prototype = {};

ColorGen.prototype.settings = {
    gridContainer   : 'gridContainer',
    xSquareCount    : 50,
    ySquareCount    : 50,
    xLength         : 500,
    yLength         : 500,
    gridArr         : []
};

ColorGen.prototype.totalSquares = function() {
    return (this.settings.xSquareCount * this.settings.ySquareCount);
};

ColorGen.prototype.squareDim = function(length, count) {
    return Math.round(length / count);
};

ColorGen.prototype.hueStep = function() {
    return (360/this.totalSquares());
};

ColorGen.prototype.populateGrid = function() {
    var width = this.squareDim(this.settings.xLength, this.settings.xSquareCount),
        height = this.squareDim(this.settings.yLength, this.settings.ySquareCount);

    for(var i=0, k = this.settings.xSquareCount * this.settings.ySquareCount; i < k; i++ ) {
        var square = document.createElement('DIV');

        square.setAttribute("style", "background: hsla("+(Math.round(this.hueStep() * i))+", 100%, 50%, 1.0); width: "+width+"px; height: "+height+"px; display: inline-block; position: relative;");

        this.settings.gridArr.push(square);
    }

};
    ColorGen.prototype.setGridContainer = function() {
    document.getElementById(this.settings.gridContainer).setAttribute('style', 'width: '+this.settings.xLength+'px; height: '+this.settings.yLength+'px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;');
}

ColorGen.prototype.appendGrid = function() {
var gridSquares = this.settings.gridArr;

for(square in gridSquares) {
    if (document.getElementById(this.settings.gridContainer) !== null) {
        document.getElementById(this.settings.gridContainer).appendChild(gridSquares[square]);
    }
}
}

var colorgen = new ColorGen();

colorgen.setGridContainer();
colorgen.populateGrid();
colorgen.appendGrid();
```

Here's the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Ua6Mp/embedded/result/

Question: Is this an appropriate utilization of the prototype method?  If not, what is the convention for extending access to a sibling method's properties?

*I may not be phrasing this correctly.  Please feel free to edit this question if you think it could be described more clearly*

Comment: Methods of a property that is a sibling to another method of the same parent object.  Sorry if I'm not describing that very well...

Comment: an example of just that would be better... probably inline comments in your code.

Comment: one note : You are overwriting `ColorGen.prototype = {}` . it will lost `constructor` property.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `name.prototype.method = function() {}` where name is an object you are dealing with JavaScript classes. As far as I know, many JavaScript frameworks use this (maybe jQuery too). I haven't heard of properties in JavaScript classes yet.